# Unity Resources.Load<Sprite> returning null?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know there are lots of questions with the same title, but I've looked through many of them and the documentation for this method and I cannot find why this isn't working.

I have an object I need to add an image to at runtime, however Resources.Load cannot find the image.

Here is my code:

```
foreach(Card card in cards){
     var i = new GameObject(card.ToString()); 
     // card.ToString() always in format Number of Suit e.g. "2 of Clubs"

     var cardImage = Resources.Load<Sprite>("/Materials/Sprites/" + card.ToString());

     i.AddComponent<Image>();
     i.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = cardImage;

}
```

I have also tried loading in using `Resource.Load() as Sprite`, but this didn't work either. The images are all set to "Texture Type: Sprite(2D and UI)" with sprite mode Single.

The image always returns null and isn't added to the object.

I'm sure the image exists, and in the location "Assets/Resources/Materials/Sprites". Here is my file hierarchy:

[file hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGRkK.png)

(The image in question is any of the ones named Number of Suit like "2 of Clubs")

Comment: Is the sprite in the Resources folder?

Comment: @hijinxbassist  Yes, it's in "Assets/Resources/Materials/Sprites". I can add a picture of my file hierarchy if that would help?

Comment: Please include the value of `objectName` in your question, or the full string path.  It is impossible to know for sure if the path is valid without that value.

Comment: @hijinxbassist OK, I've added some more information about the objects name and file path, thanks for letting me know

Comment: 2 things to try.  1. Remove the beginning forward slash.  2. Debug.Log the value of card.ToString(), or the entire path. eg.  `var path = $"Materials/Sprites/{card}";`.

Comment: That's embarassing... Removing the slash at the beginning fixed it, cheers. Such a small thing, I thought I'd tried all the combinations I could. Thanks very much for helping!

Comment: No problem.  One tip, AddComponent returns a reference to the component, so you can write `var imageComponent = i.AddComponent<Image>()`, then you don't need to do a GetComponent right after.  cheers.  Or if you are only assigning that one you can inline it,  `i.AddComponent<Image>().sprite = mySprite;`